# Practical usage of await on the same line as the async call?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

What's the purpose of calling an async method with await on the same line?  (not what is the behavior, but what are the practical uses of this pattern).  As far as I understand, this will in effect be a synchronous "blocking" call, as execution in this context will not continue until GetDocumentAsync completes, correct?

```
Document someDocument = await db.GetDocumentAsync(documentId);
//AFAIK blocks until GetdocumentAsync completes and returns 
CalledAfterAwaitReturnsAndResultIsAvailable(someDocument.SomeProperty);
```

Most tutorials showing how to call an async method I've seen do this, and I've seen it in other's code. To me it defeats the purpose of asynchronous execution.  It would seem like to benefit from the async call, you would make the async call, without the await, and do some other unrelated sequential work(or start some other async calls) not dependent on `someDocument`, and then do the `await` to get the result of the async call and then do whatever depended on that return.  Such that your other unrelated processing can be performed while the async call is also working in another thread.  I've seen the above pattern so much, I am beginning to wonder if I am misunderstanding something.

**What is the practical application of making an async call in this way, such that it blocks until it completes?**

Comment: (no downvote here) Await methods aren't synchronous blocking calls.  They return immediately, wrapping the rest of the method in a Task (this is terribly simplistic, but you get the idea) which is then resumed (on some thread, depending) once the awaited call completes.

Comment: MSDN contains plenty of articles that explain how `async` works that can be found by searching for title of your post... Like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx.

Comment: @L.B I have, and from my observations it does block.  How it behaves is not the question being asked.  But I included a description of my understanding of the behavior in case that premise is incorrect and someone feels a need to point out my misunderstanding/incorrect premise of the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't ask how async works.  I have read many of those articles.  If the premise of my question is incorrect, please point that out.

Comment: If it doesn't block execution, and allows execution to continue before the return is available, then how can I do `someDocument.SomeProperty`  as if the return is available.

Comment: @AaronLS: The hard part you're probably having is understanding that, at some point, someone has to get the answer, and therefore is "blocked" until all the awaits down the call tree have completed.  But  this kind of thinking is incorrect.  For example, if you async call a web method in an event handler, and you wait for that call to complete to update the UI, actually you have two methods.  One that starts the process (up until the await), which returns immediately, and one that completes the call (after await) and updates the UI.  All happens on the UI dispatcher, so you don't notice.

Comment: @L.B When you talk about the UI(there is no UI in the context of my usage) I assume you are referring to code calling my method.  Yes, calling code another level up can benefit from async because my method must be marked as async, but within the context of my method, code after the await is not executed until await returns the result.  I have updated the example to perhaps clarify my **admittedly loose** usage of the term "block"

Comment: @Will Thanks Will, for understanding and focusing on what I was asking. I was forgetting about the "trickle up async keyword on method definition" kind of scenario.  I knew my usage of the term "blocking" was a little loose and probably not technically accurate, but I assumed people would focus on the question asked instead of that :/

Comment: If you used "synchronous blocking call" as "non-blocking call" it definitely confuse readers. There is really big difference between "code executed sequentially" and "this is blocking synchronous call". My assumption was your "blocking until it completes" was totally wrong and hence required 101 article... apparently it is not what your question was about - sorry. You may check something like http://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/archive/2012/11/02/understanding-c-async-await-1-compilation.aspx for inner details if interested.

Comment: About the title *... await on the async call*. This might be somewhat incorrect  terminology. Check ["Invoke the method with await"... ugh!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/03/13/quot-invoke-the-method-with-await-quot-ugh.aspx) by Stephen Toub.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks, point taken

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks.  Note I didn't use "await" as a verb acting grammatically on the method, which seems to be the main gripe of the article.  However, I have modified the title with "on the same line as" to clarify this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the key thing you are missing is that when you hit the first `await`, the function you were inside returns with a `Task<Document>` (assuming your function was declared like `public async Task<Document> Foo()`) and lets the person who called your function continue on doing other work.

The caller can then either process some other work and check on the Task later to see if it is done or he can `await` immediately himself and continue the deferred work up the chain till you hit someone who does have work to do (on Forms or WPF this goes all the way up to the Message Pump and lets the UI keep responding while you are waiting for the task to finish).

Comment: So the primary purpose of this pattern(await on same line as call) would be used whenever I want to make my own method also support async calling then, correct?

Comment: Correct, if you are doing async you will likely want to make the calling method async too (and that function's calling method, and that function's function calling method) "all the way down" to get any real benefits. Often if you can't do it "all the way down" you can get better performance just sticking with the non-async versions of the calls (This is usually true in ASP.NET uses of async)

Comment: Not arguing, I have seen the "trickling async" and understand that, but at some point though, to actualize those benefits, someone up the chain has to make call the async method with a delayed await, otherwise the whole chain behaves somewhat synchronously.  I.e. in MVC if I have a controller method mark `async`(trickled up from other async method calls), the MVC framework will call my action async method without await(i.e. delayed) so that the request handler/resources are immediately freed and don't have to wait for the action method to return.

Comment: I am going to post what I think is a more succinct answer that might be easier to understand for others in my shoe, but you pointed out the key thing I was missing, so markign this as answer.

Answer (score 8):

The `await` keyword does not call `Wait` on the task, it calls `ContinueWith`.  The result is that rather than a blocking call, you get a completion callback.

Answer (score 2):

The practical application of this pattern is when you want to trickle up/expose the async capability to other potential callers of your method.  While within the context of your method it will *appear* to behave as if it is synchronous, it is not actually blocking.  A parent caller can benefit from the child methods async capability and perform parallel processing while GetDocumentAsync processes.

```
public async Task<List<string>> ProcessDocument()
{
  Document someDocument = await db.GetDocumentAsync(documentId);
  //Since await is on the same line as the async call, 
  //  Parse will not be called until GetDocumentAsync completes and result is available.
  //Thus it appears to "block", it is not technically blocking, 
  //  as a caller of ProcessDocument can start an async call to ProcessDocument 
  //  and perform other parallel processing while GetDocumentAsync is processing,
  //  because ProcessDocument is marked async
  return Parse(someDocument.Contents);
}

public async void ApplicationStart() {

    //no await when calling async method, processing begins asynchrounously
    Task<List<string>> parseDocTask = ProcessDocument();

    //we will continue other work while ProcessDocument is asynchronously performing work
    //We can execute DoIndependentWork while at the same time ProcessDocument is working on a separate thread asynchronously
    DoIndependentWork();

    //get result of async call, either will block until result is available,
    // or if async ProcessDocument task has already completed, will continue immediately
    List<string> parsedDocument = await parseDocTask;

    //do something with parsedDocument
}
```

Comment: Another way of thinking about it is that an `async` method is *sequential*, just not *synchronous*.

Comment: One performance tip, if `Parse` does not need to be on the same thread `GetDocumentAsync` had when you went in to the function you can do [`db.GetDocumentAsync(documentId).ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to allow the compiler to put the continued work on `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(` instead of using [`SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the callback to the rest of the code.

Comment: This is pretty old, but I'm surprised no one had mentioned you can't use the await keyword in a method not marked with async. That won't compile.

Comment: @Michael Realized I was also returning a `List<string>` where it should ahve been `Task<List<string>>`, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That method logically blocks. The difference is that if the asynchronous code is a blocking IO operation, the current thread will be returned.

If a current `SynchronizationContext` exists, the continuation will be posted to that `SynchronizationContext` (usually a UI message pump); otherwise, the continuation will be posted to the thread pool.

This is an over-simplification of what's happening, but it helps getting into it.